# UbRecovering ubntu After Installing Windows

Tags: partitioning, grub2, mount, windows-7, bootloader

Recently, I installed widows 10 and I want to recovery my ubuntu bootloader

First I used this command to show my disks

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l
```

then my disks information as follow :

```
Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x4fbb3a9d

Device     Boot     Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *       206848  215246847  215040000 102.6G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2       215248894  511139839  295890946 141.1G  5 Extended
/dev/sda3       511139840 1953523711 1442383872 687.8G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda5       493389824  511139839   17750016   8.5G 82 Linux swap / Solaris

Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition table entries are not in disk order.


Disk /dev/sdb: 7.2 GiB, 7759462400 bytes, 15155200 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00068714

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *     2048 15155199 15153152  7.2G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

Then I use mount command , I face with problems

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda2,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

I use another one, the message is as:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount /dev/sda5 /mnt
mount: unknown filesystem type 'swap'
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Best Regards
Vahid

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do. What do you mean by "recovery my ubuntu bootloader". For single booting Windows use Windows bootloader.

It looks like your windows installation has overwritten Ubuntu.

First you try to mount /dev/sda2 which is an extended partition. That is not a legal operation.

Then you try to mount /dev/sda5, the old Linux swap-file. That isn't a legal operation either.

Except for the left over Linux swap, which don't hold data, there are no Linux / Ubuntu partitions on the disk listed above.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your attention
I had installed windows 10 and ubuntu on my system.
My windows 10 corrupted and I install it again.
Then in my boot loader I cant see ubuntu to choose it.
I made usb live ubuntu to recover the boot-loader (GRUB) after installing Windows.
Now I face with this problem.

Comment: Kindly note that this is a comment and not an answer. If you need to add more information edit your question or comment (when you have enough reputation).